# sql remove dots and commas from fields

Tags: mysql, sql

in mysql i can list all the meta_values of my meta_key `_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_6_fieldID_10_numInSet_0` with

```
 select * from pm_postmeta where meta_key LIKE '%_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_6_fieldID_10_numInSet_0%'
```

its  a list of user heights like 1.67 , 168 etc

i want to remove the dots on the numbers...sometimes i have 1.79 and i want 179 ... how can i do this ?

i tried

```
UPDATE pm_postmeta
SET meta_value = REPLACE(REPLACE(meta_value,',00',''),'.','')
WHERE meta_key='_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_6_fieldID_10_numInSet_0';
```

but it deleted the table row and i needed to imported again...

Comment: Are they actually numbers or at they characters representing numbers?

Comment: Do you need to just show it without dots OR update it in the DB too ?

Comment: `SELECT Replace(meta_value ,'.','') AS meta_value` you can replace it in select statement as well if just need to replace dot for view.

Comment: i want to update my db... they are numbers like 1.76 that i want to be 176

Comment: but – Arsalan i want only the meta_key  LIKE '%_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_6_fieldID_10_numInSet_0%'

Comment: `UPDATE pm_postmeta
SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value,'.','') WHERE meta_key='_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_6_fieldID_10_numInSet_0';` 
Didn't it work ?

Comment: i need to do this only on meta_keys _simple_fields_fieldGroupID_6_fieldID_10_numInSet_0 that command will do it in all

Comment: is meta_value column integer datatype ?

Comment: Hmm then add the meta key as well in the Where Condition. Let me update my above comment.

Comment: no joy 0 records updated

Comment: my mistake Arsalan  ur code worked ..tks alot man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually every depends on the data type you use to store people heights.

You say "*they are numbers*" and I assume  they're stored in a NUMERIC column (you cannot store 1.78 into an INTEGER data type).

So, assuming your original table contains something like:

```
SQL> select * from people ;
        id|  height
----------+--------
         1|  180.00
         2|    1.78
         3|  165.00
         4|    2.01
```

You basically want to update this table multiplying by 100 all heights with a fractional component:

```
SQL> update people set height = height * 100 where mod(height, 1) > 0 ;
SQL> select * from people ;
        id|  height
----------+--------
         1|  180.00
         2|  178.00
         3|  165.00
         4|  201.00
```

**Edit**

Ok, you say now that the values you want to change contain **either** commas or dots so... the column is a CHAR/VARCHAR. Something like this:

```
SQL> select * from people2;
        id|height    
----------+----------
         1|180       
         2|1.78      
         3|165       
         4|2,01
```

In this case I would use:

```
SQL> update people2 set height = replace(replace(height,'.',''),',','') where height regexp '.*[,.].*';
SQL> select * from people2;
        id|height    
----------+----------
         1|180       
         2|178       
         3|165       
         4|201
```

Answer (score 1):

If meta_value is integer then update the meta_value column to string

```
ALTER TABLE pm_postmeta ALTER COLUMN meta_value varchar(50);

UPDATE pm_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(REPLACE(meta_value,',00',''),'.','')
WHERE meta_key='_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_6_fieldID_10_numInSet_0';
```

Comment: if i list it like this : select * from pm_postmeta where meta_key LIKE '%_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_6_fieldID_10_numInSet_0%' i get all the values...some still with dots or commas  like (1.73) or (1,78) i want 173 and 178

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.*,REPLACE(REPLACE(p.`meta_value`, '00', ''),'.', '') AS meta_value
FROM `pm_postmeta` p
WHERE p.`meta_key`='_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_6_fieldID_10_numInSet_0';
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if Your `REPLACE(REPLACE` is correct, but Your `UPDATE` statement's `WHERE` condition is wrong. You are using `=` instead of `LIKE`. Use `LIKE`.

```
UPDATE pm_postmeta
SET meta_value = REPLACE(REPLACE(meta_value,',00',''),'.','')
WHERE meta_key LIKE '%_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_6_fieldID_10_numInSet_0%';
```